# Issue with developing a rearrangeable and resizable GridView in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm attempting to create a GridView in Flutter that allows for both rearranging and resizing of its elements. I've tried implementing the grid using the GridView widget, but I'm encountering difficulties in enabling both rearrangement and resizing functionalities simultaneously.

Issue Details:

Objective: To create a GridView where items can be rearranged by dragging and resized by user interaction.
Current Approach: I've used the GridView widget in Flutter and tried integrating drag-and-drop functionalities using the Draggable and DragTarget widgets. For resizing, I've experimented with GestureDetector and other interaction widgets.
Challenges Faced:
When implementing drag-and-drop, resizing functionalities seem to conflict or interfere with the drag behavior.
Resizing operations are not consistently responsive or predictable.
Code Snippets:
Here's a simplified version of the code I've been working on:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Rearrangeable GridView'),
        ),
        body: RearrangeableGridView(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RearrangeableGridView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RearrangeableGridViewState createState() => _RearrangeableGridViewState();
}

class _RearrangeableGridViewState extends State<RearrangeableGridView> {
  List<int> _items = List.generate(10, (index) => index);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ReorderableListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      children: _items
          .map((index) => Card(
                key: ValueKey(index),
                elevation: 2,
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                child: ListTile(
                  key: ValueKey(index),
                  title: Text('Item $index'),
                  leading: Icon(Icons.drag_handle),
                ),
              ))
          .toList(),
      onReorder: (oldIndex, newIndex) {
        setState(() {
          if (oldIndex < newIndex) {
            newIndex -= 1;
          }
          final int item = _items.removeAt(oldIndex);
          _items.insert(newIndex, item);
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Expected Behavior:

Users should be able to drag items within the grid to rearrange them.
Users should also be able to resize the items within the grid using some user interaction (e.g., pinch-to-zoom or other resizing gestures).
Additional Notes:

I've explored various libraries and approaches but haven't found a definitive solution that accommodates both rearranging and resizing within a GridView.
Any guidance, examples, or alternative approaches that might help achieve this goal would be greatly appreciated.

Flutter Version: 3.16.3

Certainly! Here's an example code snippet that demonstrates a basic implementation using GridView in Flutter along with drag-and-drop functionality using Draggable and DragTarget widgets:

For a resizable and rearrangeable GridView:

Resizing: Implementing resizing within a GridView often involves custom widget sizing based on user interactions. Utilizing GestureDetector or other gesture detection mechanisms, you can detect pinch-to-zoom or other resizing gestures. Then, adjust the size of the widgets accordingly, potentially using transformation matrices or by directly altering widget sizes.

Rearranging: The rearranging functionality can be achieved using the ReorderableListView widget or by combining drag-and-drop functionalities using Draggable and DragTarget widgets. These allow users to reorder items by dragging them within the GridView.

Expectations would include:

Resizing: The ability for users to perform resizing gestures (pinch-to-zoom, etc.) on GridView items, resulting in changes to the size of those items.
Rearranging: Users should be able to rearrange the order of items within the GridView by dragging them around the grid.
The challenge lies in combining these functionalities seamlessly without conflicts between resizing and rearranging operations. The expected behavior is a GridView where items can be both resized and rearranged fluidly and intuitively by the user.

If you're encountering specific issues or conflicts between these functionalities, sharing details about the methods attempted, specific code snippets, and the unexpected behavior observed can assist in providing more targeted guidance or solutions. Here is the example pictures that i want to achieve:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0cdo.png) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrEvn.png)

Comment: Why does your question look partially ChatGPT generated? Especially the "Certainly ..." paragraph. Nevertheless, I think https://pub.dev/packages/dashboard is maybe the package you would like. Although it does not have pinch-to-zoom support, it does support rearranging and resizing items on a grid. And I believe to get it exactly as you want with pinching it would be very complicated and too complex too answer in a single StackOverflow answer in my opinion. You might just want to try to dig in the code of the package I mentioned and try to learn from there if you want to make your own solution

Comment: i have also implemented that package. but this not very helpful because this is not giving me the full access of its items which i want to store on external dependencies like cloud firestore.

Comment: I have raised one more issue in it. https://github.com/Mehmetyaz/dashboard/issues/34